# Improve performance of query of database design sechema in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have implemented mongodb schema design for groups where i have a query **to get the groups of a specific user**. I am thinking to store data as given schema.
For Example

```
var GroupSchema = new Schema({ 
                        name:String, 
                        mememers: [{ 
                                userId: { Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
                         }]
                    });
```

and

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({ 
                      name:String, 
                      email:String, 
                      groups:[{ type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Group'}] 
                      });
```

But i am still confused that what query will be efficient for the query.

```
var group = Group.find({ "memebers.userId": "***UserId***"});
group.exec(function(err, groups){ });
```

or

```
var user = User.findOne({_id:"***userId**"}).populate("groups");
user.exec(function(err, user){ });
```

Please give me the pro and cons of the both the queries.